# Mac OS Terminal - Change to Recent Directory

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, terminal.app

In Mac OS Terminal, is there a way to either have the Terminal remember the directory it was on after I last quit the Terminal application or easily "cd" to a recent directory?

I often "cd" every time I start Terminal to only a couple of directories which have spaces in them, and I am looking for an easier way to do this than either typing the whole path and escaping the spaces or finding the right folder in Finder, typing "cd" and dragging the folder from Finder into Terminal.

Comment: tab completion?

Comment: @Spiff I tried tab completion, but what I did just showed me all available directories in the current directory one by one, so that didn't save any time to get me straight to the recent directory

Answer (score 0):

If you type `cd` and then start to type a path and hit 
<kbd>tab</kbd>          , it should auto-complete the name of the file or folder you were typing, if you typed enough for it to be non-ambiguous. So you can often enter paths very quickly by just typing the first couple letters of the next directory in the path and hitting `tab`.

Another approach, if it really is the same few folders every time and they don't change often, is you could add alias commands to the appropriate shell startup script to make it easy:

```
alias cda="cd /Path/to/Silly\ Directory\ with\ Spaces\ A"
alias cdb="cd /Path/to/Silly\ Directory\ with\ Spaces\ B"
alias cdc="cd /Path/to/Silly\ Directory\ with\ Spaces\ C"
```

…this example would allow you to type `cda` and it will automatically execute:

```
cd /Path/to/Silly\ Directory\ with\ Spaces\ A
```